# Disable automatic embed links

Tags: links, embed, iframe

Is there a way on current wordpress versions (5.2..), to turn of the automatic embed links(wp-embed.min.js), that will turn an url into an iframe?

I have tried plugins, snippets, functions.php ... it seams that none of them work anymore for wp latest versions.

Comment: are you using the Block Editor(Gutenberg) or WordPress default Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```php
function dequeue_embed_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script('wp-embed');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_embed_script', 9999 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that wont work two.